# Can I use an SSD as a multiboot usb as well as for storage?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, multi-boot, bootable-media

I am considering buying a 500 GB external SSD for booting Kali and Ubuntu OS from the said external drive on my Windows laptop. I am thinking of using https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ for multiboot. However, I will have unallocated space left which I want to use for storage purposes. 
Is it possible to do this? And if so please direct me as to how to do the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install these linux distros directly to the external HDD that will then be bootable - you *dont* need to use pendrive.

Just boot the linux installation media on your laptop with the external HDD plugged in and install to that target. If you install the linux boot loader to the *external* drive (recommended), to boot you'll have to use the BIOS/UEFI boot manager - Windows doesn't play nicely with other OSs.

You can leave blank space on the external HDD for any kind of storage partition you like: EXT4/XFS for linux, NTFS for windows, etc.